# JTextField getting cutoff without expanding window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I have a Java Swing application which has a [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) inside it.  I want to assign a minimum width to the field so it is expanded no matter what.  I even tried starting it with some text inside the field to no avail.

Edit: The Layout is a GridBagLayout for that particular area.

[image: The <code>JTextField</code> is being smooshed unless I expand the window more.]

Comment: What layout(s) are you using? This is key information, and so it's surprising to me that you haven't yet mentioned it.

Comment: My apologies, this is a GridBag for this particular area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what layout you are using but try

```
TextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 23));
```

or initialize the text field with

```
JTextField TextField = new JTextField(20);
```

Comment: -1 for setPref, +1 for setting the columnCount - totals to zero :-)

Comment: JTextField TextField = new JTextField(20); was the winner.  I was trying to instantiate the JTextField with a String in hopes it would clue the user in to edit the value, all the while expanding the fields columns, but this is much better.